# Centering output text in a primefaces datatable column

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have been scouring resources for a couple of hours trying to find a working solution to what I think is a simple problem: How to center output text in individual columns of a primefaces datatable?

Everywhere I look says to surround the column with a `<div>` tag, which really seems odd and inefficient to me.  Lots of places say to use style="center", which doesn't work.  Even the example given at [primefaces.org extensions showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/exporter/columnAlignments.jsf) shows this doesn't work, where they have:

```
 <p:column filterBy="#{message.country}">  
      <f:facet name="header">  
         <h:outputText value="Country" />  
      </f:facet>  
         <h:outputText value="#{message.country}" style="center"/>  
 </p:column>
```

Yet the data for country is aligned to the left.

In order to center the text in the column:

```
<p:column headerText="Last Name">
    <h:outputText value="#{item.lastName}" />
</p:column>
```

Is this:

```
<p:column headerText="Last Name">
    <div align="center">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.lastName}" />
    </div>
</p:column>
```

the only way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define styleClass attribute for p:column element and then use css to set the proper style.

```
<p:column headerText="Last Name" styleClass="centeredColumnContent">
    <h:outputText value="#{item.lastName}" />
</p:column>
```

and the in your css

```
td.centeredColumnContent{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but better to vote as a 'duplicate'... Press the close button on the question and then choose 'duplicate' and see the already voted ones and click the first

Comment: where is the "close" button ?

Comment: right below the tags of the question..., ah sorry, you need 250 reputation points for this... I always forget that.https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes... that is to see them. You need 3000 to vote. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions